Description-field in a @Model
I have a @Model class like so:
@Model
final class MyModel {

    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var obj1: Object1
    var obj2: Object2

    init(id: String, obj1: Object1, obj2: Object2) {
        self.id = id
        self.obj1 = obj1
        self.obj2 = obj2
    }
    
}

Object1 and Object2 are both structs like so:
struct Object1: Codable {

   var description: String
}

I've noticed that I get an immediate runtime error error when trying to use the model in my app with
.modelContainer(for: [MyModel.self])


Unable to have an Attribute named description

After some digging I came to the conclusion that the error is due to the description fields of Object1 and Object2. However I need those two structs to contain that specific field, because they represent incoming JSON data. How can I resolve that issue in the optimal way?

This is not reproducible, you need to include the code that generates the error.

@JoakimDanielson I updated my post, the error is not a compiler error but rather a runtime error at the moment you run the app.

I understand it is a runtime error but I don’t get that error so you need to explain what you do when this happens. Or do you mean this happens directly when you start the app?

Yes, immediately after starting the App. I also tried it with a dummy project, which I posted the code of. Same result

Don't know why the word description is a problem, there is not enough information
from your code.
But note, if you are getting the properties from JSON, then you can use CodingKeys
to rename them. For example:
struct Object1: Codable {
    var info: String
    // ...
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case info = "description"  // <--- here, description in the JSON data
        //...
    }
}


description seems to be a no-go field for a @Model. You can find that error on this page https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/common-swiftdata-errors-and-their-solutions

Well using enum CodingKeys should fix that, right.
